# How to fix error additem in choice when reopening a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So my program do the option of close and reopen a JFrame, but when i'm doing that, the itens are multiplying each time i reopen this JFrame. I searched in my code and for open the JFrame i'm using:

```
  Menu men = new Menu();
        men.main(null);
```

so the JFrame of Menu, do the main again and is running this again for add the itens in the Choice:

```
  entrada7.addItem("option 1");
  entrada7.addItem("option 2");
  entrada7.addItem("option 3");
```

and for this, each time i reopen, is creating more and more of this options. How do i fix that??
a print of what is happening:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/slWzD.jpg

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should probably not reopen the **JFrame** the way you are doing it. You should rather use the `setVisible`method. For example if you use a button to close the JFrame, call the method in the following way:

```
jframe.setVisible(false);
```

Where the jframe variable references your unique JFrame instance.

If you open it via a click on a button or on a menu item, test if the jframe instance exists, if it does not exist you create it otherwise you set its visibility to true. So this would look like:

```
if (jframe != null) {
   jframe.setVisible(true);
} else {
   // call your initial JFrame creation routine here
}
```

You should also take care of the case where the user clicks on the small upper-left (or upper-right depending on the OS) close button. In that case you do not want the Jframe to be deleted but only hidden. Therefore you should define the **setDefaultCloseOperation** behavior of the JFrame at the moment of its creation. In this particular case use something like:

```
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

This instructs Swing to hide the JFrame when we click on the close button.

In any case you can avoid the duplication of items if you check first that your JComboBox has no items inside (`getItemCount() == 0`) or if you explicitely call the `removeAllItems()` method before inserting the new items.

The first option would look like:

```
if (entrada7.getItemCount() == 0) {
   entrada7.addItem("option 1");
   entrada7.addItem("option 2");
   entrada7.addItem("option 3");
}
```

And the second option would be:

```
  entrada7.removeAllItems();
  entrada7.addItem("option 1");
  entrada7.addItem("option 2");
  entrada7.addItem("option 3");
```

In first case items will be added once and only once. In second case if items were already added, they will be removed before being added again. First option is of course better.

Comment: How do i call this JFrame when you check if its not NULL ??

Comment: You have to have a instance variable declared somewhere in your main class with something like ```JFrame jframe;```. In this case the jframe variable refers to your JFrame instance. How you name the variable is totally up to you.

Comment: yeah, but the check is for see if the "other" frame is open?? i don't know how to declare the "other" jframe on "this" main